# Is there a synonym for 'synergy' that has a negative connotation?

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a word that describes a situation, where two processes with a negative outcome (in software development) combined together lead to a stronger negative effect.

Comment: You can say the one *compounds the problem* (or *error*) of the other. In psychology, a shared psychosis in which two people feed of the delusions of each other is known as a [*folie à deux*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folie_à_deux), as I learned in an episode of the X-Files (though I can never call the first word to mind when I want it).

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember seeing a "dyssynergy". It would make sense, because the Greek of "synergy" means "working together", and that does not have to be working *well* together. Suggest you google for that, and "dysergy" too.

Comment: Dyssynergy appears to be a medical term: http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/dyssynergy

Comment: Which shouldn't preclude it from being used elsewhere, in a more general sense as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to the [incompatibility](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incompatibility) of the two systems:

> - the quality of being unable to exist or work in congenial combination. (AHD)

- the two systems are incompatible and there can not be any synergy between them.

Comment: This is the opposite of synergy. I am looking for 'synergy of errors'.